# How can I improve this program?

Tags: python

1. Asks the user for a number
2. If the user enters `'q'`, quits the program.
3. If the user enters a non-integer value, output: `"Please enter a number"` and ask for the first number again.
4. If the user enters an integer, convert it to `int()` and ask for the second number.
5. If the user enters `'q'` for the second number, quit the program.
6. If the user enters a non-integer value for the second number, output: `"Please enter a number."` and ask for the second number again
7. If the user does enter an integer, convert it to `int()`.
8. Display their quotient (Keep in mind that you cannot divide by 0.)

**This is what I have made:**

```
print("Give me two numbers and I will divide them.")
print("Enter 'q' to quit.")

while True:
    first_number = raw_input('\nFirst number: ')
    if first_number != 'q':
        try:
            first_number = int(first_number)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number.")
            continue
    else:
        break
    while True:
        second_number = raw_input("Second number: ")
        if second_number != 'q':
            try:
                second_number = int(second_number)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a number.")
                continue
        else:
            break
        try:
            print(first_number/second_number)
            break
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("You cannot divide by 0.")
```

Comment: If your code works, you should use code review rather than SO. They give a deeper review.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's a first obvious improvement: the code for getting the first and second number is the same so it should be factored out as a function.

Comment: You should put some reusable code in functions. Look at the code you use for entering a number. That's unneeded duplication. [edit: @brunodesthuilliers: Great minds think alike ;)  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious improvement as bruno and Matthias point out is to factor out the user input logic into its own function. Something like this might do:

```
def get_user_input():
    while True:
        response = input('Please enter a number: ')
        if response == 'q':
            return False, None
        try:
            return True, int(response)
        except ValueError:
            continue


def main():
    print('Give me two numbers and I will divide them.')
    print('Enter \'q\' to quit.')

    continue_program, first_number = get_user_input()
    if not continue_program:
        return

    continue_program, second_number = get_user_input()
    if not continue_program:
        return

    try:
        quotient = first_number // second_number
        print('{} / {} = {}'.format(first_number, second_number, quotient))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('You cannot divide by zero')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example run (happy path)**

```
Give me two numbers and I will divide them.
Enter 'q' to quit.
Please enter a number: 10
Please enter a number: 6
10 / 6 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Useful thing: [sentinel](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) to iter() value for this kind of scenarios

```
import sys
def get_number(display_msg=""):
     sys.stdout.write(display_msg) # OR partial function can be used. 
     for response in iter(input, 'q'): # sentinel
        try:
            return int(response)
        except ValueError:
            continue
first_number = get_number(display_msg="Please enter 1st the number: ")
second_number = get_number(display_msg="Please enter 2nd the number: ")
if isinstance(first_number, int) and isinstance(second_number, int):
     #..do something with first_number, second_number
```