# Usage of the function main()?

Tags: python, coding-style, program-entry-point

I am curious whether there is any difference between these two implementations:

```
def main():
    somecode()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and alternatively:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    somecode()
```

except that you may import the function `main()` from the module

Comment: `main` isn't anything special, just a function that improves understanding... meaning it's the "main" part of the program where everything happens. Wrapping other function calls into one function makes it more clean IMO. It's also a place to include your argument logic and other stuff.

Comment: You make C/C++ devs more happy with the former :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only practical difference I can think of is something that applied to an answer I gave earlier today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41889538/1636276).

Defining the main logic in its own function `main()` rather than directly within an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block makes it easier to handle cases where the program should prematurely end:

```
def main():
    ...
    if not continue_program:
        return

    ...
    if not continue_program:
        return

    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To have gotten the same behaviour directly out of the `if` block, I'd have needed to nest several conditional bodies (or used something ugly like `sys.exit()`).

Comment: why not putting those if statements after 'if __name__== '__main__ '':

Comment: @freude If I had done so, the main body of my code would not have been executing within a function, meaning I wouldn't be able to use `return` and therefore requiring I use ugly nested conditional blocks as I said in the answer.

Comment: @freude Also, code running in a function is more efficient than code running in the global context because local name lookup is faster than global name lookup.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the code exactly like given, then directly calling `somecode()` looks cleaner to me:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    somecode()
```

This is because in Python, `main` is just another function and not a special function like in C/Java.

However, if your main function calls multiple functions, then

```
def main():
    somecode1()
    somecode2()    
    somecode3()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

is cleaner than the below alternative, reason being, that now, the interaction of different functions make the code modular and the wrapper function can now be imported elsewhere.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    somecode1()
    somecode2()    
    somecode3()
```

---

Note that,

```
def main():
    somecode1()
    somecode2()    
    somecode3()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

is equivalent to, and main is again just another name for a function here

```
def somecode():
    somecode1()
    somecode2()    
    somecode3()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    somecode()
```